# ScrollView's offset messed up when switching views in TabBar

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

The question says it all.  Whenever I switch views in a TabBar, if the scroll view is scrolled down, it will subsequently scroll 1.5 times the scroll offset.  Is there anyway to stop the ScrollView from scrolling extra when I switch views?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I`d fixed it by switching off AutoLayout mode. But I believe it should be another solution.